# Setting Environment variables in .venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, python-venv, openai-api

I am using .venv to create a virtual environment to use for a project. Within this project, I need to access the OpenAI GPT3 environment. For this, i have an API key, but I want to store it as an environment variable. Because I use windows and VS-Code to work on my project, a lot of attempts have already failed. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you referring `venv` as a virtual environment? Or is it a file? Are you trying to set environment variables inside of your virtual environment?

Comment: I am using venv as a virtual environment. i have a .env file reading `export OPENAI_API_KEY="..."`  and a normal python file reading `openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")`. All this is opened with VS-Code and i am trying to set the variable inside my virtual environment.

Comment: Could you show where you created `.env` and how you store environment variables in your `.env`?

Comment: I stored the .env in the same directory where the script running it is stored. The .env does only contain the code above, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the system environment in the settings.json file like this:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "OPENAI_API_KEY": "xxx"
  },
```

And add this in the `.env` file:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY=xxx
```

> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the export command and set your key with

```
OPENAI_API_KEY="..."
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesnt seem to work